# Library fat file not work

Tags: ios, boost, lipo

I'm trying to use fat file for Boost 1.54.0 in my iOS project. Here is info about result file from `lipo -detailed_info` command:

```
Fat header in: boost.framework/boost
fat_magic 0xcafebabe
nfat_arch 5
architecture armv7
    cputype CPU_TYPE_ARM
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V7
    offset 108
    size 2963176
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture armv7s
    cputype CPU_TYPE_ARM
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V7S
    offset 2963284
    size 3079048
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture i386
    cputype CPU_TYPE_I386
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_I386_ALL
    offset 8916872
    size 2830880
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture x86_64
    cputype CPU_TYPE_X86_64
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_X86_64_ALL
    offset 11747752
    size 3015296
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture arm64
    cputype CPU_TYPE_ARM64
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64_ALL
    offset 6042332
    size 2874540
    align 2^2 (4)
```

When I try to build for real device (iPad Mini Retina, *arm64*) I'm getting link error:

```
ld: archive has no table of contents file 'boost.framework/boost' for architecture arm64
```

I could build for *armv7* simulator without errors. What could be a reason of the error?

Comment: If you're familiar with CMake you can check [this project](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter). I use it to build fat (armv7,armv7s,arm64,i386,x86_64) libraries like boost, openssl, gtest, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it this way:

```
ranlib yourlibrary.a
```

Comment: Sorry for delay with marking answer as correct one. This command helped my too.

Answer (score 0):

Update my own answer:

Hyndrix's answer saved my day!!!!!!

After read his answer, I tried use

`ranlib src/boost-xcode5-iosx/ios//build/arm64/libboost.a`

But it doesn't work.

So I tried 
   `rablib src/boost-xcode5-iosx/ios/framework/boost.framework/boost`

I got some logs like:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: for architecture: armv7 file: /Users/src/boost-xcode5-iosx/ios/framework/boost.framework/boost(libboost_serialization_stl_port.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: for architecture: armv7s file: /Users/src/boost-xcode5-iosx/ios/framework/boost.framework/boost(libboost_serialization_stl_port.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: for architecture: i386 file: /Users/src/boost-xcode5-iosx/ios/framework/boost.framework/boost(libboost_serialization_stl_port.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: for architecture: x86_64 file: /Users/src/boost-xcode5-iosx/ios/framework/boost.framework/boost(libboost_serialization_stl_port.o) has no symbols`

But then I rebuild the Xcode project it finally works for iOS Device now.

Thank you so much and I gave you an up vote.

John, you should mark his answer as the correct one.

<s>I think it's because you are trying to build it for type "iOS Device" other than the real device.</s>

It works fine if choosing the actual device or simulator.

But it is showing the exact same error msg if I choose "iOS Device".

Hope this will help you.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but when I need to build version for distribution, I usually use _iOS Device_. Also could be a case when I don't have any device and need to create IPA. So I'm not sure it is a reason.

Comment: have you figured out why it's not working? When I use "lipo -info ~/src/boost-xcode5-iosx/ios/framework/boost.framework/boost" Architectures in the fat file: /Users/leyong/src/boost-xcode5-iosx/ios/framework/boost.framework/boost are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64   arm64 is showing up, but Xcode seems not pick it up.